# webpack - manifest.json not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I am using `React` for website development.
There is an error when running the application.
[image]
[image]

I checked the `Sources` in Inspector, there is an manifest.json but showing error.
[image]

Folder Structure:
[image]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

webpack/webpack.base.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

const utils = require("./utils");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.jsx",
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": utils.resolve("src")
    },
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset",
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 8192
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|json)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"] // ?name=[name].[ext] is only necessary to preserve the original file name
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "public/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      inject: true,
      favicon: "public/favicon.ico",
      manifest: "public/manifest.json",
    })
  ]
};
```

webpack/webpack.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const base = require("./webpack.base");

const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = merge(base, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  output: {
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3030,
    static: true,
    static: "dist"
  },
  plugins: [new Dotenv({ path: "./.env.development" })]
});
```

webpack/utils.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  resolve: function (dir) {
    return path.join(__dirname, "..", dir);
  }
};
```

Comment: The docs say `devServer.static` should be a string or object, would be good to remove this ambiguity.

devServer: {
    static: true,
    static: "dist"
  },

Answer (score 2):

Based on your file structure and webpack config, you have manifest located in the `public/` directory, which is not referenced. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#directory

You may want to change your config to something like—

```
  devServer: {
    port: 3030,
    static: [
      { directory: utils.resolve("dist") },
      { directory: utils.resolve("public") },
    ]
  },
```

FWIW, the webpack/utils.js file seems superfluous - `Path.resolve()` does exactly that.

Comment: it works now! but how can I figure it in production config, which does not use `devServer `